# Angular (input) directive doesn't work in iOS

Tags: angular

The below code works just fine, but not in iOS? Oh, and (keyup.enter) doesn't work in iOS either...

```
        <input type="text" class="mainSearch" aria-label="Search" autocomplete="off" placeholder="Search" value="" id="search" formControlName="textSearch" dir="ltr" spellcheck="false" aria-haspopup="true" (focus)="focusSearch()" (focusout)="focusOutSearch()" (input)="onSearchChange($event.target.value)">
```

Comment: How about `(keyup)` event?

Comment: (keyup.enter) does not work in iOS either